# Optimizing alternating textures in libgdx opengl

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm making a game using libgdx and each of the characters on screen is made up of two textures (body and head images) when drawing thousands of these textures the amount of render calls is very high because the texture needs to keep rebinding as alternating textures are drawn. If I draw the heads all first then the bodies I only make 2 render calls and my frame rate is great. However doing this makes the z order wrong which can easily be seen when the characters pass by each other. Is there anyway to optimize or cache these textures so that they can be drawn in the right order and also minimize opengl binds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Texture packing to reduce the amount of opengl rebind. See :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer

Answer (score 0):

You shoul keep a z index for your objects and using Comparator class sort them in a sequence you want , before drawing them on a batch

lets assume you have a DisplayObject class which instance is your visual object which has getZ() function to retrieve the z index of the object
    store your display objects in an array

```
Array<DisplayObject> displayObjects

declare a comparator one time

comparator = new Comparator<DisplayObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(DisplayObject object1, DisplayObject object2) {
            return (int) Math.signum(object1.getZ() -
                    object2.getZ());
        }
    };
```

...

in your render function
sort your objects using comparator

```
  displayObjects.sort(comparator);
```

draw all your objects

```
for(DisplayObject displayObject : displayObjects) {
       batch.draw(displayObject.body, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
       batch.draw(displayObject.head, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
}
```

for more info about Comparator you can open this link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 0):

You need split loop:

```
for(DisplayObject displayObject : displayObjects) {
    batch.draw(displayObject.body, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
    batch.draw(displayObject.head, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
}
```

for 2 loops if head and body placed on different TextureAtlasses, because every Texture switching invoke flush():

```
for(DisplayObject displayObject : displayObjects) {
    batch.draw(displayObject.body, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
}

for(DisplayObject displayObject : displayObjects) {
    batch.draw(displayObject.head, displayObject.getX(), displayObject.getY());
}
```